# GNOME Flashback on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, desktop-environments, gnome-flashback

Can you install the GNOME Flashback desktop environment on Ubuntu Server 18.04 and beyond?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install GNOME FlashBack session on 18.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

and then select *GNOME FlashBack (Metacity)* on login screen.

But as it is a server system I recommend to switch it back to console login as default target:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

and run GNOME FlashBack manually on demand:

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```